# Implication in linear logic

Tags: logic, computer-science, linear-logic

Linear logic abandons the structural rules of weakening and contraction.

I wanted to know whether we have $p ⊸ p$ in linear logic.

Can anyone help?

Comment: linear logic uses exhaustion - once p is used it becomes null, like with computer variables x=0;y=x+1, now x is null. so we need to write, $p,p; p\multimap p$. both p's are now null.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: I see the idea, but _in linear logic_ that's not quite accurate. Once the variable `p` is used, you just cannot mention it again. "Now `p` is null" means that you can use `p` but it now has a different value. Also, "null" doesn't exist in linear logic.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\par}{\unicode{8523}}$Not exactly.   We have *Linear Implication*, $\,a \multimap b\,$ , (the lollipop operator) which can be defined by linear negation and multiplicative disjunction, $\,a^\bot \par b\,$ .

Comment: Since the OP asked about $p\to p$, it would be worthwhile to add that the linear implication from $p$ to itself is valid in linear logic.  Also, when I've seen $\to$ used in linear logic, it's always meant either linear implication (when folks like me can't draw a lollipop) or intuitionistic implication (linear implication from $!a$ to $b$), and either of these meanings will make $p\to p$ valid.

Comment: @AndreasBlass : for future reference, $\multimap$ is `\multimap`.

Comment: @StevenTaschuk Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\par}{\unicode{8523}}$

Under Linear logic, we have the following derive:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\frac{}{p\ \vdash\ \ p}{\;init}}{\vdash\ \ p^\bot,\ p}{\;(\cdot)^\bot R}}{\vdash\ \ p^\bot \par p} \;\par\!R$$

The system I chosen can be found in the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-linear/). It have the benefit that it is fully symmetric.

As mentioned by the other answer, the proposition at the end is the definition of the linear implication $\multimap$. So we have shown that $p \multimap p$ is a theorem in Linear Logic. QED.